# Maximo Individual User Result Set Timeout from Start Center

Tags: sql-server, maximo

I have an individual user that is experiencing timeout/ extensive load time issues with his result sets.

The result sets that have issues are dynamically tied to the specific user's account, but no more than 300 entries are populated by each query used. Opening the same result set with several other users does not reproduce this error.

I have mimicked the individuals user settings with a test user and can not reproduce the error.

The specific error that is produced when a timeout occurs follows...

BMXAA4210E - Database error number 1205 has occurred. Invalid SQL queries are logged in the log file. Check the SQL query to identify the error.

The query does not seem to have any issues. I have no trouble running it with other users, or via Microsoft SQL Server Manager. This is literally and isolated user error, from different devices on different networks.

Any troubleshooting advice is appreciated.

Comment: This is a SQL Server deadlock error. Your question will be better if you state what module the query is running from, what action is being performed, and what version of SQL Server is running.

Answer (score 0):

Error 1205 for SQL Server is a dead lock. SQL Server is not known for handling row locks well.

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/16/sql-server-fix-error-1205-transaction-process-id-was-deadlocked-on-resources-with-another-process-and-has-been-chosen-as-the-deadlock-victim-rerun-the-transaction/